# While loop problem.The result isn't what I expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am new to Python and Stackoverflow in general, so sorry if my formatting sucks and I'm not good at English. But I have a problem with this code.

```
n = int(input("Fibonacci sequence (2-10): "))
a = 0
b = 1
sum = 0
count = 1
f = True
print("Fibonacci sequence up to {}: ".format(n), end = " ") 
while(count <= n):
      print(sum, end = " ")
      count += 1
      a = b
      b = sum
      sum = a + b
```

This is the result of the code

```
Fibonacci sequence (2-10): 2
Fibonacci sequence up to 2: 0 1
```

And this is the result that I expect.

```
Fibonacci sequence (2-10): 1
Invalid Number!
Fibonacci sequence (2-10): 15
Invalid Number!
Fibonacci sequence (2-10): 10
Fibonacci sequence up to 10: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
```

Comment: Where do you expect `Invalid Number!` to come from? I don't see that anywhere in your code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to add an additional validation step to make sure that the input is in the desired range. This should do it.

```
while True:
    n = int(input("Fibonacci sequence (2-10): "))
    if n<2 or n>10:
        print("Invalid Number!")
    else:
        a = 0
        b = 1
        sum = 0
        count = 1
        f = True
        print("Fibonacci sequence up to {}: ".format(n), end = " ") 
        while(count <= n):
              print(sum, end = " ")
              count += 1
              a = b
              b = sum
              sum = a + b
        break
```

Edit: To @Barmar's point, a loop on the outside would help avoid rerunning the code in case the input isn't within the desired range.

Comment: I think there's also supposed to be a `while` loop around it, to retry when they give an invalid number.